# nested ajax in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to achieve run a few functions which have ajax calls inside, In sequence. I am not able to do this asynchronously since they both start at the same time.

This is my code :

```
function engine_start() {
    a1();
    a2();
}

a1() {
    $.ajax(
        url: // some code and url
    }).then(function(data) {
    if (some_condition()) {
        console.log("finished a1. success");
    }
});
};

a2() {
    $.ajax(
        url: // some code and url
    }).then(function(data) {
    if (some_condition()) {
        console.log("finished a2. success");
    }
});
};
```

I want `a2()` to execute only after `a1()` is successful, which in my case is at `finished a1. success` . Note `some_condition()` also contains internal ajax requests so I need to take care of that too.

So My ideal run would be something like this :

```
1) engine_start()
2) a1 starts executing. 
3) a1 finishes 
4) a2 starts executing.
5) a2 finishes
```

Comment: "I want a2() to execute only after a1() is successful, which in my case is at finished a1." — So put the call to `a2()` after that "finished a1" statement!

Answer (score 1):

You should use some sort of callback mechanism.

```
function engine_start() {
    a1(a2);
}

a1(callback) {
    $.ajax(
        url: // some code and url
    }).then(function(data) {
    if (some_condition()) {
        console.log("finished a1. success");
        callback(); // Will execute a2 when a1 is done executing.
    }
});
};

a2() {
    $.ajax(
        url: // some code and url
    }).then(function(data) {
    if (some_condition()) {
        console.log("finished a2. success");
    }
});
};
```